Wrap around 2D coordinates of numpy array
I have a (5, 5) 2D Numpy array:
map_height = 5
map_width = 5

# Define a 2D np array-
a = np.arange(map_height * map_width).reshape(map_height, map_width)

# a
'''
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
'''

I can wrap this array around on both of its axes using 'pad()':
a_wrapped = np.pad(array = a, pad_width = 1, mode = 'wrap')

a_wrapped
'''
array([[24, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 20],
       [ 4,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  0],
       [ 9,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  5],
       [14, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 10],
       [19, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 15],
       [24, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 20],
       [ 4,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  0]])
'''

The 2D coordinates of (5, 5) 'a' are computed (inefficiently) as:
# 2D coordinates -
# 1st channel/axis = row indices & 2 channel/axis = column indices.
a_2d_coords = np.zeros((map_height, map_width, 2), dtype = np.int16)

for row_idx in range(map_height):
    for col_idx in range(map_width):
        a_2d_coords[row_idx, col_idx][0] = row_idx
        a_2d_coords[row_idx, col_idx][1] = col_idx


# a_2d_coords.shape
# (5, 5, 2)

I want to wrap this 2D coordinates array 'a_2d_coords' as well by doing:
a_2d_coords_wrapped = np.pad(array = a_2d_coords, pad_width = 1, mode = 'wrap')

# a_2d_coords_wrapped.shape
# (7, 7, 4)

It also wraps the 3rd axis/dimension which should not be done! The goal is that the coords of a[1, 4] = (1, 4) and its neighbor's coords to right hand side (RHS) should be a[1, 0] = (1, 0). This is wrapping around the x-axis. Similarly, y-axis 2D coordinates should also be wrapped.

It's not very clear to me what you expect as the output. Could you add some example for this part? What is the final shape?

First of all, you can simplify your calculation of the 2D coordinates as follows:
a_2d_coords = np.moveaxis(np.mgrid[:map_height, :map_width], 0, -1)

Let's check if this still produces the same result:
import numpy as np

# For the check, use different height and width values to detect swaps
map_height, map_width = 3, 7

# Original implementation for coords
a_2d_coords_given = np.zeros((map_height, map_width, 2), dtype = np.int16)

for row_idx in range(map_height):
    for col_idx in range(map_width):
        a_2d_coords_given[row_idx, col_idx][0] = row_idx
        a_2d_coords_given[row_idx, col_idx][1] = col_idx

# Proposed implementation for coords
a_2d_coords = np.moveaxis(np.mgrid[:map_height, :map_width], 0, -1)
# Equality check
assert np.all(a_2d_coords == a_2d_coords_given)

Second, if you note that np.pad's pad_width argument can also take axis-specific values, then you can achieve the desired coordinate padding as follows:
a_2d_coords_wrapped = np.pad(a_2d_coords, mode="wrap",
                             pad_width=((1, 1), (1, 1), (0, 0)))

Now we pad both axis 0 and axis 1 with one leading and one trailing value ((1, 1)), but leave axis 2 alone ((0, 0)).
Altogether, we have:
import numpy as np

map_height, map_width = 5, 5
a = np.arange(map_height * map_width).reshape(map_height, map_width)

a_2d_coords = np.moveaxis(np.mgrid[:map_height, :map_width], 0, -1)

a_2d_coords_wrapped = np.pad(a_2d_coords, mode="wrap",
                             pad_width=((1, 1), (1, 1), (0, 0)))
print(a[a_2d_coords_wrapped[..., 0], a_2d_coords_wrapped[..., 1]])
# Prints
# [[24 20 21 22 23 24 20]
#  [ 4  0  1  2  3  4  0]
#  [ 9  5  6  7  8  9  5]
#  [14 10 11 12 13 14 10]
#  [19 15 16 17 18 19 15]
#  [24 20 21 22 23 24 20]
#  [ 4  0  1  2  3  4  0]]

Further simplification
We can simplify the code even one step further by providing a_2d_coords/a_2d_coords_wrapped as a 2×H×W array rather than a H×W×2 array:
import numpy as np

map_height, map_width = 5, 5
a = np.arange(map_height * map_width).reshape(map_height, map_width)

a_2d_coords = np.mgrid[:map_height, :map_width]

a_2d_coords_wrapped = np.pad(a_2d_coords, mode="wrap",
                             pad_width=((0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 1)))
print(a[*a_2d_coords_wrapped])
# Prints
# [[24 20 21 22 23 24 20]
#  [ 4  0  1  2  3  4  0]
#  [ 9  5  6  7  8  9  5]
#  [14 10 11 12 13 14 10]
#  [19 15 16 17 18 19 15]
#  [24 20 21 22 23 24 20]
#  [ 4  0  1  2  3  4  0]]

Mind the * in a[*a_2d_coords_wrapped], which is necessary for "unpacking" the coordinates, so that two H×W arrays rather than one 2×H×W array are provided for indexing.

a[*a_2d_coords_wrapped] gives the error:
*a[a_2d_coords_wrapped]  - SyntaxError: invalid syntax

@Arun (1) What Python version are you using? The used syntax maybe only works for later versions of Python. (2) The following should work instead, in any case: a[a_2d_coords_wrapped[0], a_2d_coords_wrapped[1]]
